# JTable coloured row headings appearing where table is not

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am creating a JTable with 3 columns, and have set the colour of the headings to be color.CYAN.

The problem is that after the JTable ends, the rest of the row is still coloured CYAN, even though there should not be a table there at all.

I have tried fixing the number of columns but cant seem to do it.

Below is my code:

```
class SimpleTableExample extends JFrame {

     public static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

     public static void frameGui(JPanel panel, String name){             
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);            
            frame.setContentPane(panel);    
            frame.setSize(500,200);      
            frame.setVisible(true);
     }       

    public static JPanel Table(){    
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());    
        String columnNames[] = { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3" };    
        String dataValues[][] =
        {
            { "12", "234", "67" },
            { "-123", "43", "853" },
            { "93", "89.2", "109" },
            { "93", "89.2", "109" },
            { "93", "89.2", "109" },
            { "93", "89.2", "109" },
            { "93", "89.2", "109" },
            { "93", "89.2", "109" },
            { "93", "89.2", "109" },
            { "279", "9033", "3092" }
        };

        JTable table = new JTable( dataValues, columnNames );
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100);
        table.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF );          
        JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
        header.setBackground(Color.cyan);    
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        topPanel.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );        
        return topPanel;    
    }

    public static void main( String args[] )
    {    
        frameGui(Table(),"TEST");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That would be the expected behaviour, as the `JTableHeader` expands the entire width of the `JScrollPane`'s headers area.

Instead, change the `JTableHeade`r's renderers, like you would the `JTable`'s dell renderers

Take a look at [`JTableHeader#setDefaultRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/JTableHeader.html#setDefaultRenderer(javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer)) for more details